# Inject database context into classes using interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, dependency-injection, ninject.web.mvc

I'm looking to inject the database context into all classes that implement my interface [similar to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115453/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-classes-that-implement-an-interface).

What I have

```
public abstract class Service
{
    public Service(Context context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public Context Context { get; }
}
```

Each service class will have an interface with a method

```
interface IRecipeTypeIndexService
{
    IEnumerable<RecipeType> GetAll();
}
```

All service classes will inherit the abstract `Service` class, so my concrete class at the moment looks like

```
public class RecipeTypesIndexService : Service, IRecipeTypeIndexService
{
    public RecipeTypesIndexService(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<RecipeType> GetAll()
    {
        return Context.RecipeTypes.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

And my ninject bindings look like

```
Kernel.Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
Kernel.Bind<Service>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

What I would like to do is have it so that my Interface `IRecipeTypeIndexService` and other service interfaces I create inherit another interface `IService` which is Ninject binds to the abstract `Service` class, so all concrete classes that implement an `IWhateverService` must have a constructor that injects the database context to the base class, so my concrete class looks like this:

```
public class RecipeTypesIndexService : IRecipeTypeIndexService
{
    public RecipeTypesIndexService(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<RecipeType> GetAll()
    {
        return Context.RecipeTypes.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Is this possible? This is the first time I've ever used Ninject and I'm new to using dependency injection.

Comment: I think you'll need to add a private setter to the Context property in your base class: public Context Context { get; private set; }

Comment: It's private set anyway as it doesn't have a setter and is set in the constructor

Comment: Context = context will not work as the Context property is read only (it only has a getter)

Comment: In the absence of a setter it can be set in the constructor. I have integration tests that call the concrete service and call the database. It's the same as a readonly property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I realise in hindsight that this is not possible to do.

As I've set up Ninject so that anywhere with the context in the constructor will have an already initialised context, I don't need the abstract class.

My service class will then look like this:

```
public class RecipeTypesIndexService : IRecipeTypeIndexService
{
    private Context context { get; }

    public RecipeTypesIndexService(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<RecipeType> GetAll()
    {
        return context.RecipeTypes.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

I don't need an abstract base class at all.